# LibVLCSharp - Play file from zip archive

Tags: .net-4.6, libvlcsharp

I'm trying to improve some of my already-existing app in WinForms, that uses libvlcsharp to play locally storaged files.
I need to add support for playing file (usually h264 mp4) inside zip.
I can handle it, if i use MemoryStream in the middle - to cache in-zip file content:

```
static public Stream StreamFromZipFile(string archivePath, string filePath)
{
            ZipArchive zipArchive = ZipFile.OpenRead(archivePath);
            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry zipArchiveEntry in zipArchive.Entries)
            {
                if (zipArchiveEntry.FullName.Equals(filePath, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return zipArchiveEntry.Open();
                }
            }
            throw new FileNotFoundException("No " + filePath + " in " + archivePath);
        }


Stream inFileStream;
Stream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
inFileStream = StreamFromZipFile(filePath, inFileName);
inFileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
media = new LibVLCSharp.Shared.Media(LibvlcHandlerMain.libVLC, new StreamMediaInput(memoryStream));
_vlcMediaPlayer.Play(media);
```

if I use new StreamMediaInput(inFileStream) instead, I get random results (in most cases - error, sometimes it plays by accident ;))
I can guess it's some race condition - libvlcsharp reads unfinished (or empty) file.
Can I somehow skip caching whole file in memory?

Comment: Did you try to set the MemoryStream position to 0 after the copy?

Answer (score 0):

It was buggy zip implementation - works fine after switching to DotNetZip

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).